# Let $A_{\alpha}$ be the $\alpha$-rotation matrix. Prove $A_{\alpha}^T = (A_{\alpha})^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, inverse

> Let $A_{\alpha}$ be the alpha-rotation matrix. Prove $A_{\alpha}^T = (A_{\alpha})^{-1}$
>
> In other words, prove $A_{\alpha}$ transpose = $A_{\alpha}$ inverse.

First of all, what is a rotation-matrix? And what does that imply about the $\alpha$-rotation matrix? What does that make $A_{\alpha}$?

Comment: What is a rotation matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. You can also [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/26550d59-ac83-4329-bdd2-d8374da4fe84/view-source) how I have formatted your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the rotation matrix is given by:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha\\
\sin \alpha&\cos \alpha 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and its transpose by:

$$M^{T} = \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \alpha & \sin \alpha\\
-\sin \alpha&\cos \alpha 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now can you show $MM^{T} = I$? (This will imply $M^{T} = M^{-1}$! Also be sure to think about WHY this is the rotation matrix)

Comment: Okay, I get it, but I still don't understand _why_ that is the rotation matrix. I remember my professor going on about that matrix and its use in rotating a vector (line?) about the origin of the xy-cartesian plane. I didn't fully understand what he was talking about when he was explaining it. So you have a vector x, and you multiply it by the rotation matrix. Won't that just give you the rotation matrix scaled by x? Also, wouldn't this only work for vectors that are 1 by 2?

Comment: That's exactly right! Suppose you have a $1$ by $2$ vector denoting coordinates for a point in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then if we wish to show that $M$ corresponds to rotation about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, it suffices to show that rotates basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and fixes the origin. If we make a smart choice of basis vectors, say, $(0 1), (1 0)$ can you show (perhaps pictorally) that the rotation matrix does what your professor claims it does? (again, it should fix $(0 0)$, and rotate $(0 1)$ and $(1 0)$ as claimed: the unit circle as a picture should help here.

Answer (score 2):

A rotation matrix is an element of the class of orthogonal matrices. Since all orthogonal matirices' transpose is equal to their inverses, this applies to all elements of the set, including the rotation matrix.

Comment: An Orthogonal matrix is a 2 by 2 matrix whose determinant (ad-bc) is 1, correct? My professor has not covered this yet, but I gather that is what it means from the wiki post about the rotation matrix.

Comment: Not exactly. The matrix is not necessarily a $2$ by $2$ matrix. It should be, however, a square matrix. You can find all the necessary information about the orthogonal matices here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix There is a slight difference beween an orthogonal and orthonormal matrix but in wiki they are treated as the same.